# How to use a component in multiple places via a sharedModule in Angular2

Tags: angular

Experienced Angular 1 guy here, but just can't get a concept as I move to Angular 2 this weekend. Spent a day on this and ended up in circles so perhaps someone can help.

I am trying to include a ui component into multiple routes (modules?). From what I keep reading, the cleanest way to do this is to create a shared module that exports the components I want to be available to multiple other components.

With this in mind, I have created a stripped back project straight from the angular-cli to try to bring the MainNavComponent into both the AppModule, as well as a seperate route's module (About).

It displays as expected in the main app component html, but throws the below error if trying to include it in the about component html:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'app-main-nav' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-main-nav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-main-nav' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<app-main-nav></app-main-nav>
```

I realise there is no need to include a main nav in the app and in the about route, it is just for example purposes.

Am I not understanding the function of a shared module, or is my implementation just wrong?

Hard to write the entire code structure, so I have made a test bed project as a public GitHub repo where you can see how it is all structured.

https://github.com/IamAdamJowett/angular-2-test-bed

You can see the error if doing a `ng serve` on the above repo and going to http://localhost:4200/about. Thanks a bunch all.

Comment: Try to move AboutComponent from AppRoutingModule to AppModule. AppRoutingModule  doesn't import your share module. Component always gets directives that available within module. AppRoutingModule doesn't have any directives and pipes despite route directives and AboutComponent

Comment: While it didn't directly work as it broke routing if about component was removed, it did spur me to include SharedModule into the routing module as well which solved the issue. Not sure if that is best practice or not but it works. Thanks for the jolt :)

Answer (score 1):

So in the end the solution was that because I was using a dedicated routing module, I needed to bring the SharedModule into that routing module as well so that the routes could use it (bringing it into the AppModule was not enough). Thanks to @yurzui for the spur that got me on the right path.

I have updated the test repo with the change in case anyone is curious or has the same issue after using --routing with the angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

After having done a few Angular2 projects, I have stabilized on the following format for `SharedModule` and `AppModule`, and it always works for me.

In all other modules, simply import the `SharedModule`

**SharedModule**:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

// **import all angular modules that will be shared**
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

// **import all shared third-party modules**
import { TranslateModule } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import { ResponsiveModule } from 'ng2-responsive';

// **import all shared services of your app**
import { MyServiceA, MyServiceB, MyServiceC } from './services';

// **import all shared components, directives & pipes of your app**
import { MyComponentA, MyComponentB, MyComponentC } from './components';
import { MyDirectiveA, MyDirectiveB, MyDirectiveC } from './directives';
import { MyPipeA, MyPipeB } from '../pipes';

// **import any other shared sub-module**
import { MyOtherSharedSubModule } from './shared-sub.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // import all modules to share
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        TranslateModule,
        ResponsiveModule,
        MyOtherSharedSubModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        // Declare all shared components/pipes/directives
        MyComponentA,
        MyComponentB,
        MyComponentC,
        MyDirectiveA,
        MyDirectiveB,
        MyDirectiveC,
        MyPipeA,
        MyPipeB
    ],
    exports: [
        // export all shared modules/components/pipes/dirctives
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        TranslateModule,
        ResponsiveModule,
        MyOtherSharedSubModule,
        MyComponentA,
        MyComponentB,
        MyComponentC,
        MyDirectiveA,
        MyDirectiveB,
        MyDirectiveC,
        MyPipeA,
        MyPipeB
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [
                // Add all shared services
                MyServiceA,
                MyServiceB,
                MyServiceC
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

**AppModule**:

```
// ** import all angular modules**
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';

// **import other modules that require .forRoot()**
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

// **import third-party modules that require .forRoot()**
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';

// **import AppComponent, AppRoutesModule etc**
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutesModule } from './app-routes.module';

// **import SharedModules
import { SharedModule } from './shared';

// **import other root-level components
import { LoginComponent, ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components';

// **create loader/config factories for third party modules if required
export function translateLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateStaticLoader(http, './assets/i18n', '.json');
}

export function translateLoader(): any {
    return {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: translateLoaderFactory,
        deps: [Http]
    };
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // **declare only root level components here
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        ForgotPasswordComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, // <=== Must import
        HttpModule,    // <=== Must import

        // **import other modules that require .forRoot()**
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
        FlexLayoutModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(translateLoader()),

        // **import the SharedModule**
        SharedModule.forRoot(),

        // **import AppRoutesModule**
        AppRoutesModule
    ],
    providers: [
        // **specify root level services (if any)**
        // **specify service for APP_INITIALIZER (if any)**
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I'll save that for future reference. Didn't solve the issue unfortunately as it pretty much mirrored my structure apart from the fact I am using a routing module.

Seems I needed to bring the SharedModule into the routing module as well for it to work.